How override replace one DNS name with another?
With /etc/hosts I can define my own IP address for some DNS name. But what if I need to replace DNS name? For example, all HTTP request from my machine that sent to example.com are sent to foo.com?
At first glance this should be simple just edit some file and OS replaces example.com with foo.com and make resolution after that. But I have no idea how to this. Is it supported by default in Linux or additional software should be installed?
UPDATED
Q: Why do not point example.com to foo.com IP?
A: Because both hosts are in cloud. So there is no single IP address for redirection. That's why I can not get IP and used it for resolution.

In theory, if you ran your own DNS server, you could do this - while I run it networkwide adguard home lets me do that . I'm not aware of anything that does dns rewriting at the client level. Its a little involved initially but works pretty well.

Why don’t you want to just point example.com to foo.com’s IP address, like you said? Is there a reason? Maybe I’m missing something.

In other words, why do you want resolution to occur after domain redirection?

Is there a specific reason, or just wanting to know?

@security_paranoid question updated

@Cherry Thanks, that makes much more sense.

I don’t think there are settings to do this, but it would be easy with a local dns server (e.g. dnsmasq), or with a simple reverse HTTP server.

Would you be opposed to either of these?

What are you actually trying to do? This sounds like an XY problem

Shooting from the hip, put 127.0.0.1 example.com in your hosts file, then run ncat -kl 8080 -c 'ncat foo.com 8080' on the host
This is my cute quick and dirty way to get it done, configuring a DNS server to do this for you might be smarter.
